# Which HTTP verb should I use to add many items to a collection?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, rest, crud

In REST if you want to replace an entire collection you use:

```
PUT with /resourses
params=[{name:'Daniel', age:'19'}, {name: 'John', age: '17'}]
```

If you want to create a new item you use:

```
POST with /resources
params={name:'Daniel', age:'19'}
```

I dont want neither of them, what I want is to add many items to the resources without having to call

```
POST /resources
```

many times

Im looking for something like:

```
STRANGEVERB /resources
params=[{name:'Daniel', age:'19'}, {name: 'John', age: '17'}]
```

To add them to the existing collection

Comment: It is advisable to not make up new HTTP verbs. That is, if you *do* wish for standard HTTP clients/browsers/servers/proxies to work ..

Comment: Use `POST`. Debating the most appropriate verb for this operation is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `POST`, just check on the server-side if an array or single object has been POSTed. Don't try and make up HTTP verbs.

If you feel it is essential to separate the routes here, use a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against making up HTTP verbs. If you are creating new objects, use the `POST` verb. Also, batch `POST`ing is not a good idea as each object could fail or succeed for different reasons, which would issue different messages. Now you have to handle those.

There is a reason why many SaaS providers (including top providers like 37 Signals) implement single object `POST`s. That way you can handle each one individually.

If you really are set on doing batch `POST`s, then follow the RESTful methodology and create a resource that represents the batch and just internally runs the object processing, but you will still be returning a single code like 201 when successfully created or 207 if it is a multi-status response.

Good luck.

Comment: There is always the 207 status: The 207 (Multi-Status) status code provides status for multiple independent operations. The individual status's can then be returned in the response body. See: http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/207_-_Multi-Status

Comment: @MarjanVenema I referenced 207 in my answer as the solution if OP was set on doing multiple object processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the array of hashes and create each object individually. It's the best practice for a reason, David.

```
persons = [{:name => "Joe", :age => 10},{:name => "Blow", :age => 10}]
persons.each do |person|
  Person.create(person)
end
```